# System.Data.SQLite "No such Table" error occures when executing Query

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB designed using "SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1" I have used the System.Data.SQLite.

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and have added my DB in the Resources and this is my connection string

`sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source="+CryptoFile.Properties.Resources.Database1+".db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");`

it preforms

`mySQLconnection.Open();`

with no problems it opens the Database...
However .. when I try to process/Execute a Query the following line:

`SQLiteDataReader reader = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();`

causes this Error ... what might be causing the problem ?

`SQLite error
no such table:`..*Tablename*

cause the connection is used over and over the connection part is in 1 function returns the value to SQLite Connection in other forms, so don't bother with the namings here I have used the Finisar.SQLite...
and all the code has worked before ...but because I couldn't publish the project with the database I have used the System.Data.SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there can be 2 reasons for this problem.

First - connection is made to the right database but there is no such table there.

Second - connection is made to the wrong database. in such case it gives no error. It makes a database file at the specified location. Even Opens the database. but gives this error when fetching data. In such case the specified location will contain a database of 0 KB.

Comment: Its a 4KB database ... 
and neither ... but thanks for the help