# i got exception "Unable to open the database file" how to solve it

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

here i am using  sqlite data base .and code for this are here:

```
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = 
         "insert into users(name, password, priviledges) values(" +
          "'" + UsernameText.Text.Trim() + "', " + "'" + 
         QuickMethods.MD5(PasswordText.Password.Trim()) + "', " + "524287" + ")";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO company VALUES('name','" + CompanyName.Text.Trim() + "');";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO company VALUES('address','" + CompanyAddress.Text.Trim() + "');";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO company VALUES('phone','" + CompanyPhone.Text.Trim() + "');";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO company VALUES('email','" + CompanyEmail.Text.Trim() + "');";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
}
```

I got exception at line **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()** how to solve it.

Comment: And which `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` throws it?

Comment: Side note: You can use `string.Format` to create much nicer looking CommandText strings.

Comment: You have a `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` immediately below the `conn.Open()`. What's the purpose of this? It looks like a non-op. (Or is that the line throwing the error?)

Comment: at the runtime when line occurs  "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" ,then window open with name "SQLiteEXception was unhandled " and i showed "View detail.." and i found this line in curly braces {"Unable to open the database file"}.

Comment: @AdamV according to your comment i deleted line   "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" but i  got same thing at it below line  cmd.CommandText = "insert into users(.....

Comment: It actually sounds like the error is on the `conn.Open()` line (and the following line, whatever it is, is being highlighted).

Comment: Do you have write access to db file? You may also have it open somewhere, like in admin app.

Comment: @ValBakhtin : how it open somewhere ?

Comment: Check the ConnectionString and make sure it's pointing to the db file.

Comment: Please read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your first `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is the culprit. The one below connection opening.

I think it gives error there because command is not set till that time. Comment it and it should fine.

**EDIT**

If that did not work
there can be 2 reasons for this problem.

First - connection is made to the right database but there is no such table there.

Second - connection is made to the wrong database. In such case it gives no error. It makes a database file at the specified location. Even Opens the database. But gives this error when fetching/updating data. In such case the specified location will contain a database of 0 KB.

My Answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989984/system-data-sqlite-no-such-table-error-occures-when-executing-query/9990115#9990115) will help you

**Note/Warning related to question, not related to answer:**

Always be aware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use Parameterised Query (the one with @).

[More on SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Good warning, however it's not really an answer to this question